# Употребление наращивания после числительных

Tags: словообразование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в предложении "В 44-м регионе намечаются глобальные перемены" нужно ли наращивание. Как в этом случае расценивать название региона - как порядковое или как количественное числительное?

Answer (score 2):

Это порядковое числительное, наращение правильное. Если бы слово "регион" стояло перед числом, то было бы: "*В регионе 44*". 
Вот ссылка на правила: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Меня всегда удивляла формулировка правила о наращениях после числительных. Складывается впечатление, что этих окончаний много, что количество букв в наращении зависит от предыдущей буквы (гласной или согласной). Получается такое сложное и условное правило, которое нужно каждый раз вспоминать.

Поэтому я предлагаю  **очень простую формулировку правила.**

1. Наращение делается только **для порядковых** числительных, чтобы отличить их от количественных числительных.
2. При наращении из окончания порядкового числительного **убирается одна буква.**

И это всё!

**Пояснение**

1) Порядковые числительные склоняются как прилагательные.

[Таблица окончаний имён прилагательных](https://izamorfix.ru/rus/morfologiya/padeji_prilag.html)

2) Как мы видим, окончаний не так много, некоторые из них повторяются. Что интересно —  каждое окончание состоит **из двух или трех букв.**

И тогда получается: при наращении из окончания **убирается одна буква.** Если было три буквы, то останется две, а если было две буквы, то останется одна. А про гласные и согласные ничего упоминать не надо.

3) Окончаний с тремя буквами мало: *ОГО/ЕГО, ОМУ/ЕМУ, ЫМИ/ИМИ*. В этом случае в наращении будет всегда две буквы.

4) **Проверим:**

В 44-м регионе —  в сорок четверт/ом регионе, окончание ОМ, две буквы, поэтому оставляем одну букву.

В мае 45-го года —  в мае сорок пят/ого года, окончание ОГО, три буквы, поэтому оставляем две буквы.

Comment: Благодарна за исчерпывающий ответ

Answer (score 1):

Числительное *сорок четвёртый*, конечно, порядковое.

С правилами наращения можно ознакомиться, например, [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99)

В частности:

`По закрепившейся традиции наращение должно быть однобуквенным, если последней букве числительного предшествует гласный звук…`

Так что наращение здесь нужно и оно правильное. Правда, я бы не стал называть регионы по номерам.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение